# Circuit state preparation using amplitude encoding

Tags: quantum-state, circuit-construction, machine-learning, quantum-circuit

I am following an example of preparing an input state using amplitude encoding from this [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319964232).

How to calculate $\beta_1^1$ using given formula above? In my understanding, $\beta_1^1 = 2\arcsin(\frac{\alpha_2}{\alpha_0})$ which is not equal to zero.

[image]

Comment: I came here and 4 people had already voted to close due to "needs more focus'. The reason for this is because you're asking more than one question in a single post.

Comment: I have modified the question. Could you open it again?

Comment: Thanks for narrowing it down! Still, the question body says "How to calculate β11 using given fomula above?" and you haven't given any "formula above".